# Is there any way how to remove chrome close button in kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

When i start chrome with -kiosk mode, when i move mouse at the top of the screen - the close button appears from the top, is there any way how to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Open chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui and disable 
`Experimental fullscreen exit UI`

That fixed it for me.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/yUbhOUJuJaY). Screenshot of this "feature" is on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/76dazq/small_cosmetic_change_in_dev_v63_exit_fullscreen/).

Comment: As of this date, the `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui` flag doesn't seem to be available anymore

Comment: @WouterVanherck Yes. If you get a solution please reply.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in target of chrome shortcut

> `--user-data-dir=c:\temp --kiosk`

for example

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=c:\temp --kiosk www.google.com`

Comment: Starting the browser wit the `--kiosk` property seems like a good alternative solution. Keep in mind that this will change other functionalities too.

Comment: Thank you so much, "--user-data-dir" was the missing part to hide the title bar in Chrome in kiosk mode!

Comment: None of these are working in mac.
rm -rf ~/tmpdir && /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/Users/porpro/tmpdir" --app="http://localhost:8080"